# MongoId Unique Value inside Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I try to do something like a find_or_create_by on an Array field.

Here is my model:

```
class Contact
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Attributes::Dynamic

  field :id, type: String
  field :emails, type: Array
  field :phones, type: Array
  field :first_name, type: String
  field :last_name, type: String
  field :fullcontact, type: Hash
end
```

I will create those Contacts with an email.

Emails field is an Array, for exemple I want to add test@test.com. How can I do a find_or_create on the array emails. If I have a Contact with test@test.com I want to find it or create one with email inside emails.

Comment: What does `find_or_create_by(:emails => 'test@test.com')` do? MongoDB generally peeks inside arrays automatically.

Comment: find_or_create_by work for a find but not a create, he return that we try to insert string instead of array. But with a find and after a create if we don't find it's ok, thanks !

Comment: Right, the automatic array handling is a bit incomplete, haven't used Mongoid/MongoDB for a bit. Could have kludge in a `before_save` to arrayify a scalar `emails`?

Comment: I used a find then if it's nil I create. It works now, thx !